# Excel 2007 transpose/combine multiple rows into one

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have data like so:

```
1001NCCN    3618127
1001NCCN    208478
1001NCCN    207316
1001TEMN    409889
1001TEMN    801651
1001TEMN    273134
1001TEMN    208478
1001TEMN    207316
```

I need to transpose/combine the rows that have matching values in the first column with a final result like so:

```
1001NCCN    3618127 208478  207316      
1001TEMN    409889  801651  273134  208478  207316
```

I looked at Pivot Tables, and filtering but neither seemed like they can give me what I need.  Is there a way to do this within Excel?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but it might matter, so: is the data sorted on the first column? Specifically, do you know if every instance of `1001NCCN` (and the like) will always be adjacent to one another, or is it possible to have them split?

Comment: @DMA, Yes every instance is adjacent to one another.  They are not sorted alphabetically but I can do that if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a VBA solution

it relies on like rows being grouped, so sort first if you need to

Just select the first cell in your range and run...

```
Sub Mergeitems()
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim rw As Range

    Set rw = ActiveCell

    Do While rw <> ""
        ' for each row in data set
        '   find first empty cell on row
        Set cl = rw.Offset(0, 1)
        Do While cl <> ""
            Set cl = cl.Offset(0, 1)
        Loop

        ' if next row needs to be processed...
        Do While rw = rw.Offset(1, 0)
            cl = rw.Offset(1, 1)       ' move the data
            Set cl = cl.Offset(0, 1)   ' update pointer to next blank cell
            rw.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp   ' delete old data
        Loop

        ' next row
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked great on the 21,000 row spreadsheet!

Answer (score 3):

IMO the simplest way to perform such a task is by means of Google docs.
Copy your data in an empty Google spreadsheet. Then at, say, F1 write:

```
=UNIQUE(A:A)
```

and at G1 write:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=F1)
```

and copy down.
Then copy results and paste them back into Excel.

Comment: Interesting approach.  I will look into this the next time I find myself in this situation.