# Rearanging complex excel data

Tags: microsoft-excel, transpose

I have a complex set of data that I need to rearrange in excel.

The table looks something like this

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| ID | Text A | Text B | Text C | Text D |
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1  | xx     |        | yy     | zz     |
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2  |        | aa     | bb     |        |
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 3  | cc     |        |        | dd     |
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

The result I need to output is essentially a combination of a transpose and a coalesce. But I have no idea how to tackle this problem in Excel.

```
+----+------+
| ID | Text |
+----+------+
| 1  | xx   |
+----+------+
| 1  | yy   |
+----+------+
| 1  | zz   |
+----+------+
| 2  | aa   |
+----+------+
| 2  | bb   |
+----+------+
| 3  | cc   |
+----+------+
| 3  | dd   |
+----+------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel 2007 transpose/combine multiple rows into one](https://superuser.com/questions/244507/excel-2007-transpose-combine-multiple-rows-into-one)

Comment: reference question gives you a good start, after performing unpivot all you need is to delete extra column and remove rows with blank cell in second column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn one row into multiple rows in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/889201/turn-one-row-into-multiple-rows-in-excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that the original data is in *Sheet1* and the output will be placed in *Sheet2*.

Running this short macro:

```
Sub ReOrganizer()
    Dim N As Long, nCols As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet

    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    nCols = 5
    k = 2

    For i = 2 To N
        Item = s1.Cells(i, 1)
        For j = 2 To nCols
            If s1.Cells(i, j) <> "" Then
                s2.Cells(k, 1) = Item
                s2.Cells(k, 2) = s1.Cells(i, j)
                k = k + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

will take data like this in *Sheet1*:

[image]

and produce this in *Sheet2*:

[image]