# How do I transpose a table with repeated key values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, python, shell-script, sed, awk

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Column A | Column B
      10 |      0.1
      10 |      0.2
      10 |      0.3
      20 |      0.4
      20 |      0.5
      20 |      0.6
```

I need to transpose it to look like this:

```
 10 | 20
0.1 | 0.4
0.2 | 0.5
0.3 | 0.6
```

Almost 2k different values in Column A, for each one there is exactly 1k values in column B, which might repeat.

Is there an automated way of doing this?

Comment: Use a PivotTable!

Comment: Similar question here: https://superuser.com/q/244507/76571  You can probably use the solutions there and then just add a simple transpose step to the end to get what you want.

Comment: A PivotTable doesn't keep the data, I can only extract certain functions that will apply to all columns (min, max, average, stddev, sum, product, etc)

Comment: I also tried `vlookup`, but it finds only the last value of column B for each value of column A

Comment: @Excellll indeed those answers would solve my problem, but neither the VBA script or the Google Spreadsheet solution were able to handle the amount of data. They crash with memory errors (even though I still have plenty of free memory)

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Excel 2016 from Office 365

Comment: I know you have a Python solution, but you can also do this with `Power Query`, `PQ` can handle about 1GB of data in the 32-bit version; much more in the 64-bit version.

Comment: The problem wasn't memory, nor CPU. At least in the task manager the notebook was in ~50% load, after excel crashes it drops to ~45%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This python script did the trick:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('inputcsv', delimiter=',')
keys = sorted(set(data[:,0]))

result = np.array([])

for k in keys:
    col = data[np.where(data[:,0] == k)][:,1]
    if not result.any():
        result = col
    else:
        result = np.vstack((result, col))
    print('key {0} finished'.format(k))

np.savetxt('final.csv', np.transpose(result), delimiter=',')
```

Comment: You found a solution to you problem, that's great! Why don't you post excerpts of the input and output files for all to review? And don't forget to accept your answer if it works for you.

Comment: Because the examples of input and output are in the question

Comment: I was suggesting you post actual input and output files because I tried running the script against your posted input and it gives an [error](https://pastebin.com/RybF7CVH). Obviously, the script expects a CSV input, so [here](https://pastebin.com/zf613j3w)'s with the input formatted accordingly. You mention there are thousands of Column A values, so I added just one and [this](https://pastebin.com/Ls8Gs8YJ) is the error I got.

Answer (score 0):

I would bake a PHP script:

```
<?php
$file = fopen($argv[1], "r");
while(!feof($file)) {
    $line =  trim(fgets($file));
    if ($line=='') {continue;}
    $line = explode(' ', $line);
    $a[$line[0]] []= $line[1];
}
fclose($file);
foreach ($a as $k=>$v) {
    echo $k,"\t";
}
echo "\n";
$a = array_map(null, ...$a);
foreach($a as $b){
    echo implode("\t",$b),"\n";
}
```

Input file (tab-separated):

```
10      0.1
10      0.2
10      0.3
20      0.4
20      0.5
20      0.6
30      0.3
10      0.9
```

Command:

```
php script inputfile
```

Output (tab-separated):

```
10      20      30
0.1     0.4     0.3
0.2     0.5
0.3     0.6
0.9
```